# Adding an image to gridlayout changes entire layout

Tags: android, xamarin, android-imageview, android-gridlayout

I'm new to Android development so I may have missed a simple problem, but i'm trying to create a login screen with an image at the top. I have my layout exactly the way I want, except when I add the image the entire layout changes. I've added a textbox with the same grid settings as imageview (LoginPageCharity) to test and it works perfectly with the textbox, but then i change imageview to visible and the textbox (textView1) to gone, my whole setup changes. Can you explain to me why this is and if possible how to remedy this? Thank you in advance! Here are the two layouts and my code.

[image: The layout I want]
[image: Layout after image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
    p1:columnCount="6"
    p1:rowCount="10"
    p1:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    p1:orientation="horizontal"
    p1:columnOrderPreserved="true"
    p1:rowOrderPreserved="true"
    p1:useDefaultMargins="false">
    <TextView
        p1:id="@+id/textView1"
        p1:enabled="true"
        p1:visibility="visible"
        p1:layout_column="0"
        p1:layout_columnSpan="6"
        p1:layout_columnWeight="6"
        p1:layout_row="0"
        p1:layout_rowSpan="3"
        p1:layout_rowWeight="3" />
    <TextView
        p1:id="@+id/textView2"
        p1:layout_column="0"
        p1:layout_columnSpan="1"
        p1:layout_columnWeight="1"
        p1:layout_row="5"
        p1:layout_rowSpan="1"
        p1:layout_rowWeight="0.3"
        p1:visibility="visible" />
    <Button
        p1:text="Log In"
        p1:id="@+id/button1"
        p1:layout_column="1"
        p1:layout_columnSpan="1"
        p1:layout_columnWeight="1"
        p1:layout_row="5"
        p1:layout_rowSpan="1"
        p1:layout_rowWeight="0.3" />
    <TextView
        p1:id="@+id/textView3"
        p1:layout_column="2"
        p1:layout_columnSpan="1"
        p1:layout_columnWeight="1"
        p1:layout_row="5"
        p1:layout_rowSpan="1"
        p1:layout_rowWeight="0.3" />
    <Button
        p1:text="Create Account"
        p1:id="@+id/button2"
        p1:layout_column="4"
        p1:layout_columnSpan="1"
        p1:layout_columnWeight="1"
        p1:layout_row="5"
        p1:layout_rowSpan="1"
        p1:layout_rowWeight="0.3" />
    <TextView
        p1:id="@+id/textView4"
        p1:layout_column="5"
        p1:layout_columnSpan="1"
        p1:layout_columnWeight="1"
        p1:layout_row="5"
        p1:layout_rowSpan="1"
        p1:layout_rowWeight="0.3" />
    <TextView
        p1:id="@+id/textView5"
        p1:layout_column="0"
        p1:layout_columnSpan="6"
        p1:layout_columnWeight="6"
        p1:layout_row="6"
        p1:layout_rowSpan="4"
        p1:layout_rowWeight="4" />
    <EditText
        p1:inputType="textPassword"
        p1:id="@+id/editText1"
        p1:layout_column="1"
        p1:layout_columnSpan="4"
        p1:layout_columnWeight="4"
        p1:layout_row="4"
        p1:layout_rowSpan="1"
        p1:text="Password" />
    <EditText
        p1:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        p1:id="@+id/editText2"
        p1:layout_column="1"
        p1:layout_columnSpan="4"
        p1:layout_columnWeight="4"
        p1:layout_row="3"
        p1:layout_rowSpan="1"
        p1:text="Username" />
    <ImageView
        p1:src="@drawable/redcross2"
        p1:id="@+id/LoginPageCharity"
        p1:layout_column="0"
        p1:layout_columnSpan="6"
        p1:layout_columnWeight="6"
        p1:layout_row="0"
        p1:layout_rowSpan="3"
        p1:layout_rowWeight="3"
        p1:scaleType="centerInside"
        p1:adjustViewBounds="true"
        p1:visibility="gone"
        p1:cropToPadding="true" />
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was:

1. Take out `textView1` as it is only "for bug testing".
2. Take out the `visibility` attribute of the `ImageView` as you always want to show it.
3. Take out the `weight` attributes of the `ImageView`.

And this is the result:

[image]

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: I don't think I explained myself well enough. I want my picture to be visible and i want it to be placed in the same area taken up as the (textView1). But when I add an image to my imageView box (which has the same grid dimensions as the textView1 box) the grid changes. textView1 is only here for bug testing. I want this picture viewable above my login without changing the formatting.

The image I'm using is found here: https://tribkiah.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/redcross2.jpg?quality=85&strip=all&w=770

Comment: How about putting the picture above the `GridLayout`?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by putting it about putting is above my GridLayout. GridLayout is a root level element.

Comment: Yes, but one can always downgrade it to be a child of root (and put a layout around both, the `GridLayout` and the `ImageView`, but hold on, I think a have a solution (at least to the problem as I currently understand it).

Comment: Thats it! Thank you for your help. It seems that I was trying to constrain my object too much and I should have just trusted it knew what it was doing. Now I know how parents feel when they let their children off into the world.

Comment: `GridLayout` is pretty difficult to handle. You could reach the same result with (two or so) `LinearLayout`(s) or even `RelativeLayout`(s).